# Autocomplete dropdown in MVC5?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

Hi i have one field in my view. That field is Customer it is a dropdown field. In that i have keep dropdown as select option to select the value. But i like to change that field as Autocomplete dropdown.

[image]

In the above image  I have customerName field as dropdown field but i keep it by search and select option. But now i like to change this to autocomplete dropdown like which is mention the in the below image.

[image]

**My view Code**

```
 @Html.Label("Customer Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text" })
```

**My jquery Code**

```
  $(function () {
     debugger;
    $.ajax(

   '@Url.Action("GetVisitCustomer", "VisitorsForm", new { Area = "Sales" })',{
       type: "GET",
       datatype: "Json",
       success: function (data) {
       $.each(data, function (index, value) {
       $('#CustomerID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerID + '">' + value.DisplayName + '</option>');

                });
               }
             });            
           });
```

**My Controller Code to get Customers and load in the field**

```
  public JsonResult GetVisitCustomer()
    {
        var objCustomerlist = (from c in db.Customers where c.IsDeleted== false select c).ToList();
        return Json( objCustomerlist,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I tried to explain my issue.  Any one help to resolve this issue. I tried many ways but its not working.  So any one understand my issue and give some solution or suggesstions.

The Code which i have tried

My View Code

```
 @Html.Label("Customer Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(Model=>Model.CustomerID)
```

My Jquery Code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $("#CustomerID").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax(
                     '@Url.Action("GetVisitCustomer", "VisitorsForm", new { Area = "Sales" })', {
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return
                            { label=item.CustomerID, value= item.DisplayName
                            };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

But this code is not working

Advance Thanks..

Comment: what problem are you facing with the code you have now?

Comment: [jquery-ui autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)

Comment: i will post my code that i tried but it is not working

Comment: Now check my code which i tried stephen

Comment: Hi @Susan if I had answered your question, can you kindly mark my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Kindly see code below:

**HTML**

```
            @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.CustomerName, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.CustomerName, new { @class = "form-control"})
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.CustomerID)
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CustomerName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetVisitCustomer", "Home")',
                datatype: "json",
                data: {
                    Areas: 'Sales',
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (val, item) {
                        return {
                            label: val.Name,
                            value: val.Name,
                            customerId: val.ID
                        }
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#CustomerID").val(ui.item.customerId);
        }
    });
});
```

**CODE**

```
    public JsonResult GetVisitCustomer(string Areas, string term = "")
    {
        var objCustomerlist = db.Customers.Where(c => c.IsDeleted == false)
                        .Where(c => c.CustomerName.ToUpper()
                        .Contains(term.ToUpper()))
                        .Select(c => new { Name = c.CustomerName, ID = c.CustomerID })
                        .Distinct().ToList();
        return Json(objCustomerlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Sample screenshot**

[image: Img 1. Shows the autocomplete dropdown]
[image: Img 2. Shows the selected Customer Name and the corresponding Id added to the CustomerID hidden field.]

Comment: Denchu i tried that second method as per you said it didnt showing any error..It hit the json (GetVisit Customer) and calculate the value which i  typed in the text box but after calculating it didnt show the Calculated values in the view to select the option same as which is mentioned in the above image..

Comment: Hi @Susan. I updated my answer and added screenshots so you can visualize the result. What I did is, return 2 data from the JsonResult, the CustomerID and CustomerName. In the sample above, once the appropriate Customer name is selected from the autocomplete dropdown, the CustomerID hidden field will be populated with the correct ID, which I showed on the second image.

Comment: ok Denchu lets i have a try and check and further if i got issue means i will inform with you

Comment: Btw, why do you need to add in the `Areas` parameter? Do you also need it as filter for the Customer List in the JsonResult method?

Comment: Denchu that is we combined two projects in single application my project is coming in sales under areas . My forms all are in Sales under Areas so only i used as like that.

Comment: Hi @Susan see the update I made under **JS** and **Code**. I added the Areas parameter under data with the value "Sales". For the Code part, I added the Areas parameter as the first parameter, and updated the term to have a default empty string value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114194/discussion-between-denchu-and-susan).