# MVC Autocomplete Dropdown Troubles

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am currently trying to use Jquery-UI's autocomplete functionality similar to as shown here: [Autocomplete dropdown in MVC5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585676/autocomplete-dropdown-in-mvc5) ... I have reviewed many posts now using jquery autocomplete helper and have been unable to find my issue. My problem is that the ajax call goes out and succesfully hits the GetSchools action, the action will return the correct and expected data, but then nothing happens. No autocomplete options are displayed and no console errors appear. The `success` function in my js gets hit with the appropriate number of items in `data` but nothing happens after that.  All help is appreciated.

My Controller Actions:

```
    public ActionResult ManualVerifications()
    {
      var vm = new ManualVerificationsViewModel();

      return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ManualVerifications(ManualVerificationsViewModel vm)
    {
      return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetSchools(string term = "")
    {
      var schoolList = _schoolRepo.GetAll()
        .Where(c => c.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()))
        .Select(x => new { label = x.Name, value = x.Id })
        .Distinct().ToList();

      return Json(schoolList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My View (ManualVerifications.cshtml):

```
@model ProEdVerificationPortal.Data.ViewModels.Verification.ManualVerificationsViewModel

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedSchoolName, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SelectedSchoolName, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SchoolId)
```

and the JS rendered in the view:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#SelectedSchoolName").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/verification/getschools',
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {
          term: request.term
        },
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          response(data);
        }
      })
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
      $("#SelectedSchoolName").val(ui.item.label);
      $("#SchoolId").val(ui.item.value);
      return false;
    },
    focus: function (event, ui) {
      $("#SelectedSchoolName").val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

and my very simple viewmodel:

```
  public class ManualVerificationsViewModel
  {
    public string SelectedSchoolName { get; set; }

    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
  }
```

an example of data return from my controller would be the following:
`[ { label: "SeedSchool", value: 1 }`

and a picture from the console.log(data) results:
[image]

Comment: Posted an answer, but without seeing an example of your data that is being returned to your AJAX, it's hard to know what's happening. Also check for any errors in console. Please update your question.

Comment: @Twisty question has been updated- same behavior still occurring

Comment: Also updated my answer.

Comment: @Twisty I have updated my JS to match yours exactly (other than yours has a small syntax error that I fixed) and have posted a picture of the logged console.log(data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're result data is not correct. Based on the following:

```
public JsonResult GetSchools(string term = "")
{
  var schoolList = _schoolRepo.GetAll()
    .Where(c => c.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()))
    .Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, Id = x.Id })
    .Distinct().ToList();

  return Json(schoolList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I would expect your resulting data set is like:

```
[{
  "Name": "Berkley",
  "Id": 1001
},
{
  "Name": "UCSF",
  "Id": 1002
}]
```

Autocomplete does not know what to do with this data. It's especting an array with specific object data:

> An array of objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

You'll want to adjust your results to fit this format.

```
public JsonResult GetSchools(string term = "")
{
  var schoolList = _schoolRepo.GetAll()
    .Where(c => c.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()))
    .Select(x => new { label = x.Name, value = x.Id })
    .Distinct().ToList();

  return Json(schoolList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#SelectedSchoolName").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/verification/getschools',
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {
          term: request.term
        },
        success: function (data) {
          response(data);
        }
      })
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
      $("#SelectedSchoolName").val(ui.item.label);
      $("#SchoolId").val(ui.item.value);
      return false;
    },
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
      $("#SelectedSchoolName").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**Update 1**

Including a lite example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4Lv9psd8/

**Update 2**

An example with AJAX functionality and some other flare: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4Lv9psd8/6/

Comment: I've updated my question with your suggestion and also am now showing an example of what my controller is returning. I am still getting the same behavior. no console error and nothing is happening after hittinh my success JS function

Comment: @peggy expanded my answer. If you're still seeing issues, I would add `console.log(data);` to your `success` callback. This way we can see what the callback is getting.

Comment: @peggy also the `return false;` is important in your `select` callback.

Comment: I have updated my JS to match yours exactly (other than yours has a small syntax error that I fixed) and have posted a picture of the logged console.log(data)

Comment: @peggy take a look at this fiddle and let me know if it closely resembles and works like your current MVC: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4Lv9psd8/5/ Let me know if I need to correct or adjust.

Answer (score -2):

I see 3 things, the first is that you don't have `[HttpGet]` in the top of the `GetSchools` Method. place it, in second place in the ajax you must place the type type: "`GET`", and send the data via the url, in example:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/verification/getschools?term='+request.term,
        datatype: "json",
        type: "GET"
      });
```

in the web config check that you allow high size responses and place a error function in the ajax to check may be if something wrong. And is important never send direct responses from the database, serialize that to a local object, in other cases json response crash.

Comment: `GET` is the default method type for `$.ajax()`.