# Need ASP.NET MVC create view page to change information provided by user to foreign key values

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am working on creating a website that accesses a table in SQL Management Server. The user needs to be able to view, edit, delete, and create new entries within the table using my site. The table that is being used is called DeviceUnderTest and it has these columns: DeviceUnderTest (pk), DeviceUnderTest (nk), Notes (nk), FaultApplication (fk), Firmware (fk), Hardware (fk), Power (fk), Location (fk), PreEventTime(nk), HandleRate (nk). So far, I have created the model that connects to the main DeviceUnderTest table, as well as the other tables that the foreign key columns reference. I have created the controller, as well as an index, details, delete, and create view page. My index view is a table, and I figured out how to replace all the foreign key values with their corresponding tables from the tables they reference. The one thing I can not figure out is the create page. Users will enter the information in the form of the values that the fk columns reference, rather than the foreign key values themselves. I can not figure out how to change the user input back to the correct foreign key value so that the entry can be correctly added to the table noth in the sql server as well as within my site. If anyone has any suggestions, they are much appreciated.

Controller Code:

```
// GET: Circuit/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Circuit/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(DeviceUnderTest device)
        {
            try
            {


                    dbModel.DeviceUnderTests.Add(device);
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();

                    // TODO: Add insert logic here

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Create View Code:

```
@model Template_Website.Models.DeviceUnderTest

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DeviceUnderTest</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.pkDeviceUnderTest, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.pkDeviceUnderTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.pkDeviceUnderTest, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nkDeviceUnderTest, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nkDeviceUnderTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nkDeviceUnderTest, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nkNotes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nkNotes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nkNotes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FaultApplication.nkFaultApplication, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FaultApplication.nkFaultApplication, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FaultApplication.nkFaultApplication, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firmware.nkFirmware, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firmware.nkFirmware, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firmware.nkFirmware, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hardware.nkHardware, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hardware.nkHardware, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hardware.nkHardware, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fkPower, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fkPower, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fkPower, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location.nkLocation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location.nkLocation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nkPreEventTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nkPreEventTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nkPreEventTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nkHandleRating, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nkHandleRating, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nkHandleRating, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default " value="Create" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Index View Code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Template_Website.Models.DeviceUnderTest>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2> 




<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>

        </th>

        <th>

        </th>
        <th>

        </th>
        <th>

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.pkDeviceUnderTest)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nkDeviceUnderTest)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nkNotes)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FaultApplication.nkFaultApplication)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Firmware.nkFirmware)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hardware.nkHardware)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fkPower)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location.nkLocation)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nkPreEventTime)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nkHandleRating)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected)
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Edit", "Circuit", new { id = item.pkDeviceUnderTest } ) + "'");" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Details" class="btn btn-default" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Details", "Circuit", new { id = item.pkDeviceUnderTest }) + "'");" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Delete", "Circuit", new { id = item.pkDeviceUnderTest }) + "'");" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.pkDeviceUnderTest)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nkDeviceUnderTest)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nkNotes)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FaultApplication.nkFaultApplication)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Firmware.nkFirmware)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hardware.nkHardware)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fkPower)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.nkLocation)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nkPreEventTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nkHandleRating)
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

DeviceUnderTest Model Code:

```
namespace Template_Website.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class DeviceUnderTest
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public DeviceUnderTest()
        {
            this.TestRecords = new HashSet<TestRecord>();
        }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        [Required]    
        public int pkDeviceUnderTest { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string nkDeviceUnderTest { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string nkNotes { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> fkFaultApplication { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> fkFirmware { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> fkHardware { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> fkPower { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> fkLocation { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> nkPreEventTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> nkHandleRating { get; set; }

        public virtual FaultApplication FaultApplication { get; set; }
        public virtual Firmware Firmware { get; set; }
        public virtual Hardware Hardware { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<TestRecord> TestRecords { get; set; }
    }
    public class DeviceUnderTestModel
    {
        public List<DeviceUnderTest> device { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Hardware Model Code:

```
namespace Template_Website.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Hardware
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Hardware()
        {
            this.DeviceUnderTests = new HashSet<DeviceUnderTest>();
        }

        public int pkHardware { get; set; }
        public string nkHardware { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<DeviceUnderTest> DeviceUnderTests { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a couple of the related models? Perhaps the DeviceUnderTest model and the Hardware model?

Comment: @BattlFrog I added the DeviceUnderTest and Hardware models!

Answer (score 0):

> Users will enter the information in the form of the values that the fk columns reference, rather than the foreign key values themselves.

Why do you want to avoid using the foreign key values?  I notice you are using `EditorFor` but can't you simply use `DropdownFor` or even a JavaScript-powered autocomplete widget? This way, your users would enter the desired text but the values would be mapped in the background.

For an example of how to use `DropdownFor`, please see the MSDN docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/examining-how-aspnet-mvc-scaffolds-the-dropdownlist-helper

For an example of using an autocomplete, there is a nice answer here which uses jQuery UI: [Autocomplete dropdown in MVC5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585676/autocomplete-dropdown-in-mvc5)

Using the first example for `DropdownFor` and applying it to your code, one of your model properties would continue to look the same:

```
public Nullable<int> fkFaultApplication { get; set; }
```

While you also create a ViewBag item to contain your `SelectList` which maps your texts and values:

```
ViewBag.FaultApplicationId = new SelectList(db.FaultApplications, "FaultAppId", "Name");
```

Finally, you could make use of these properties in your view as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FaultApplicationId", String.Empty)
```

Note that the second parameter, `String.Empty`, "is the text to display when no item is selected."

Answer (score 0):

Just like user1477388 says, you can use dropdowns for each item. This way the view displays the text, but the value sent back is the id.

For example using hardware.  I'm using a viewmodel so we dont present the database models to the view.  The VM has the properties you want in the specific view.  In this case we have the  Device Under Test stuff, a select list and a HardwareId.

```
public class DeviceUnderTestViewModel
{    
    public int pkDeviceUnderTest { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string nkDeviceUnderTest { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string nkNotes { get; set; }

    public int HardwareId { get; set; } //pkHardware
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> HardwareSelectList { get; set; } //dropdown of Hardware
}
```

In the controller, populate the select lists and attach to the viewmodel:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DeviceUnderTestViewModel vm = new DeviceUnderTestViewModel();

    vm.HardwareSelectList = db.Hardware.ToList().Select(d => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = d.nkHardware,
            Value = d.pkHardware.ToString()
        });

    // populate all the other dropdowns

    return View();
}
```

In the view we render the select list:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HardwareId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HardwareIdId, Model.HardwareSelectList, "Select Hardware...", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HardwareIdId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

DropDownListFor takes the value to set first, here we are setting the hardwareid which we will save to the DeviceUnderTest as the pkHardware, then we have the populate list of Hard items for the dropdown, third is an optional string place holder, then lastly I add a bootstrap class for formatting.

Then return the model to the controller and save it:

```
public ActionResult SaveDevice(DeviceUnderTestViewModel model)
{
    using (var db = new dbContext())
    {
        DeviceUnderTest device = new DeviceUnderTest()
        {
            pkHardware = model.HardwareId,
            // continue with other items

         };
        db.Entry<device>.State = EntiyState.Added;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View();
}
```