# search result from enum list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have enum list as below and I'm trying to make it searchable as below example from w3schools because it's going to have around 60 items.so the dropdown list will be based on the search.

```
public enum LocationType
{
    Brazil = 1,
    Arentina = 2,
    Canada = 3,
    USA = 4
    etc // here i will add around another 60 items
}
```

My View

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Location" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="Location" class="form-control" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<LocationType>()"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Location" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

W3schools example
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

Comment: Have you looked at select2? https://select2.org/searching

Answer (score 1):

Below is a demo to use `Select2` in your razor:

```
<select id="locationSelect" asp-for="Location" class="form-control" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<LocationType>()" > 
</select>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/css/select2.min.css"/>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#locationSelect").select2();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: it's working fine but I don't know why the search box is not show

Comment: @Momen Alnaser Maybe your css is not applied correctly?

Comment: i didn't face issue with my css before and if yes then which section it might have the issue from not sowing the search box, btw the search is working for the items it's just not shown

Comment: @Momen Alnaser I mean the `<link rel="stylesheet"` in my anwser.Could you see it in browser F12 sources tab

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />

Comment: @Momen Alnaser It should like https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa0t5.png

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box searchable dropdown list for MVC.

You must use some kind of custom implementation.

You can use something like this: [Autocomplete dropdown in MVC5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585676/autocomplete-dropdown-in-mvc5)

Another solution would be to create a textbox for search and submit the value, use linq in the enum values and bind the new enumerable with the filtered values. If you don't want a full post, you need to do an ajax call with javascript though

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jquery plugin like 'select2' to search.
And you can use the code below to get Enum items.

```
var items = Enum.GetNames(typeof(LocationType));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a jquery plugin like this or other plugins:
http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/